# Upgrading Andriod Studio 4.2.2 not working and producing a Gradle Input/output error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am a new self teaching developer hoping to learn Kotlin development via Android Studio. I also just realized if I want to learn Kotlin/Android then
I'm also learning Gradle like it or not.

I recently install Fedora 34 then installed Android Studio from the Fedora Software repository.  Upon starting my very first tutorial on Kotlin, Gradle build failed to sync and Android Studio indicated that version 4.2.2 is a available stopping me before I have even started.  I have started Android Studio as root several times yet the upgrade does not happen.   I have googled Gradle input/out error, setting.gradle and gradle.build for any configuration that I may need to make or I may have over looked.

Project Structure
Gradle Plugin Version 4.2.1
Gradle Version 7.1.1

Gradle for current project
user home /root/.gradle
Generate .iml file is checked
Download external annotations is checked
use Gradle from 'gradle-wrapper.properties'file

I have run the following:

Gradle sycn,
Invalidate Cashes/Restart
AGP cache clean with:$ ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
Gradle upgrade v7.1.1 with SDKMAN without any assumed issues.
Grade scan  https://gradle.com/s/axcqhuiwtpfcg/activate/m55kfphbqfp5o

Close Android Studio and open as root assuming it will auto upgrade to 4.2.2 with the following:

[root@fedora var]# sudo ./lib/flatpak/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/x86_64/stable/c98dfa958bbd5225b99de3f2dc5f5947fb3993760db630edde199f6eef3e5494/files/extra/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
2021-07-15 10:03:39,933 [   6000]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator)
2021-07-15 10:03:43,869 [   9936]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk]
2021-07-15 10:03:46,968 [  13035]   WARN - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activities registered via registerPostStartupActivity must be dumb-aware: com.android.tools.idea.stats.AndroidStudioUsageTracker$ProjectLifecycleTracker$projectComponentsInitialized$1@509dc6a9
2021-07-15 10:04:07,452 [  33519]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkWritingAccessProvider)
2021-07-15 10:04:38,382 [  64449]   WARN - ues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW
2021-07-15 10:04:38,429 [  64496]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Input/output error (29 s 101 ms)
2021-07-15 10:04:38,431 [  64498]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Input/output error
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Input/output error

At this point Android Studio is now open yet the upgrade notice to 4.2.2 is still present.

Thank you for any enlightenment today.